# How can check a Software is instralled is install or not using java

Tags: java, windows, installation, system, system-information

In java I want to check whether a software is installed or not. If installed, show it. If uninstalled, then install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lokesh Kumar you need to check C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (X86), and check if software is there.. If it is not then copy files to there with Java program. If software there, then delete software files. You can use java.nio package for copying/moving/deleting files. It has all good features to work with HDD (Hard Disk Drive).

**EDIT**

If software is bundled in installer, then you can run installer program with Java using Runtime, and Process, ProcessBuilder API.

Comment: This answer is misleading. Some software requires installation with an installer, which places things in directories other than `Program Files`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic OP has not mentioned about installers, but if it is installer, then she can execute installer program with Java

Comment: OP said **Software**. Since he did not say which type, it could be either way, but your answer will not help him find it, uninstall it, or "show it" as he asked. In fact, he didn't even say it was **Windows**.

Comment: @Windows, See, OP has tagged question with Windows, so she has windows OS in his laptop, and I have updated question, sorry answer with how to execute installer.

Comment: @RealSkeptic does this clears your doubt? Even you can post question on it here. Just tag it with Java, I will catch up it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic sorry in his desktop, because I see standalone keyboard, so she must be having desktop, not laptop.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @TJ Thanks a lot, I will note this in my diary, and will ask for criticizing my answer to Opener of Post (OP)